# intento crear un menu de navegacion vertical desplegable pero no se despliega

Tags: html, css

Estoy creando un sistema el cual contiene un menu de navegacion vertical con varios menus y submenus y cuando quiero que se despliguen las opciones del menu vertical con el hover, ya sean del menu o del submenu. el menu no quiere desplegarse para mostrar las demás opciones, he intentado de todo y aun no logro hacer que se visualicen las opciones correctamente, por que creen que ocurre esto? omiti el codigo de mi header y solo coloco el del menu de navegacion que es el que no funciona correctamente.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        
        <nav> 

            <ul class="menu-area">
                <li><a href=""><strong>Registro</strong> </a> 

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Estudiantes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Obreros</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href=""><strong>Estudiantes</strong></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Agrupaciones</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href=#> Rock Sinfónico </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href=#> Camerata Yaracuy </a> </li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                        
                        <li><a href="">Catedra</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href=#> Cátedra de Violín </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href=#> Cátedra de Viola </a> </li>
                            </ul>

                        </li>
                
                        <li><a href="">Formacion de adultos</a>

                            <ul>
                                <li> <a href=#> Piano </a> </li>
                                <li> <a href=#> Cuatro </a> </li>                       
                           </ul>

                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li><a href=""><strong>Obreros</strong></a>

                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="">Administracion</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="">Docentes</a></li>
                        <li> <a href="">Limpieza</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>

            </ul>

        </nav>

    </div>
```

```
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0;
    clear: both;
}

.menu-area{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: aqua;
    width: 250px;
}

.menu-area li{
    position: relative;
}

.menu-area li a{
    height: 36px;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    color: black;
}

.menu-area li a strong{
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2vw;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.menu-area li:hover > a{
    color: grey;
}

.menu-area li ul,
.menu-area li ul li ul{
    background: #262626;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 300ms;
    z-index: 999; 
    left:280px;
    top: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    min-width: 250px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu-area li: hover > ul, .menu-area li ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    left: 250px;
}

.menu-area li ul li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2vw;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
}

.menu-area li ul li ul{
    left: 230px ;
    top: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy simple. es e un error muy simple suele pasar. solo tienes que eliminar el espacio entre el elemento y pseudo-clase :hover. De esta manera

```
.menu-area li:hover > ul, .menu-area li ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
left: 250px;
```

}

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda amigo, ya lo solucione

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero y te ayude en algo lo que hice, solo que me quedo en horizontal pero si funciona lo del hover. Utilice otro estilo de css, espero y te sirva de algo.

```css
 /* PROPIEDADES GENERALES */

* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
    outline: 0;
}
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0;
    clear: both;
}
#menu {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 50px 0;
    clear: both;
}

#menu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#menu ul li {
    width: 162px;
}

#menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(59,93,148,1);
    border: solid 1px #fff;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
}

#menu ul li ul li a {
    width: 160px;
    padding: 8px 0px;
    border-top-color: transparent;
}

#menu ul li ul {
    display: none;
}

/* PROPIEDADES ESPECÍFICAS */

#menu ul li ul li ul li a.primera {
    border-top-color: #fff;
}

#menu ul li.nivel1 { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

#menu ul li a.nivel2 {
    color: #000;
}

#menu ul li a.nivel1, #menu ul li a.nivel2 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

/* PROPIEDAD HOVER */

#menu ul li:hover {
    position: relative;
}

#menu ul li a:hover, #menu ul li:hover a.nivel1 {
    background-color: #6CC;
    color: #000;
    position: relative;
}

#menu ul li:hover  ul.nivel2, #menu ul li a:hover  ul.nivel2{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;left: 0px;
}

#menu ul li ul li a:hover ul.nivel3, #menu ul li ul li:hover ul.nivel3 {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 161px;
    top:0px;
}

#menu ul li ul li a:hover {
    border-top-color: #000;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body> 
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="nivel1"><a href="#" class="nivel1">Registro</a>
                <ul class="nivel2">
                     <li><a href="#">Estudiantes</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Obreros</a></li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="nivel1"><a href="#" class="nivel1">Estudiantes</a>
                 <ul class="nivel2">
                    <li class="nivel2"><a class="nivel2" href="#">Agrupaciones</a>
                        <ul class="nivel3">
                            <li><a class="primera" href="#">Rock Sinfóni</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Camerata Yaracuy</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nivel2"><a class="nivel2" href="#">Catedra »</a>
                        <ul class="nivel3">
                            <li><a class="primera" href="#">Cátedra de Violín</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cátedra de Viola</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nivel2"><a class="nivel2" href="#">Formacion de adultos »</a>
                        <ul class="nivel3">
                            <li><a class="primera" href="#">Piano</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Cuatro</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
             </li>
             <li class="nivel1"><a href="#" class="nivel1">Obreros</a>
                <ul class="nivel2">
                    <li><a href="#">Administracion</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Docentes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Limpieza</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda isabel <3